# .htaccess P flag gets redirected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Im having a problem.
I got this code bellow on website example.com, for redirecting HTTP to HTTPS (which works fine).

```
# example.com
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE]
```

The problem occurs when trying to add virtual subdomain. In the subdomain's folder, there's only one htaccess file (code below), which is supposed to get content from main domain (example.com) and display it on different address (eg. subdomain.example.com).

```
# subdomain.example.com
Allow from all

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9]+)$ http://example.com/$1-$2 [P]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(css|png|jpg|gif|rss|php)$ http://example.com/$1.$2 [P]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/something-specific [P]
```

When I try to go to subdomain.example.com, I get redirected to example.com(because of the HTTP>HTTPS redirect). But I'd like to stay on subdomain.example.com and display content from example.com/.../..

If I change http to https in this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com[P]`, I get Internal Server Error 500.

Is there a way around the redirect?
Thanks for every reply.

Comment: An http status 500 is pretty meaningless. It is only the small bit of information your server published to clients. You need to look deeper and find the actual issue. For that monitor your http server's error log file. That is where you can read what the actual issue is.

Comment: Are both hosts served by the same http server? If so you don't need to implement a proxy rule at all. You can simply use two separate virtual hosts pointing to the same `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Or you use an internal rewrite to map both hosts to the same content.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I've described one thing the wrong way. The content on both sites is not 100% the same. Subdomain is supposed to display content from example.com/subdomain. (question now edited). I've contacted my hosting service for the error log file.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your comment to the question such that both hosts are served from the same http server. If so you can simply use an internal rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain
RewriteRule ^ /subdomain%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

That rule is implemented in the host configuration of "subdomain.example.com". or, if you do not have access to that in the top level distributed configuration file (".htaccess") in its `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.